# In angular, how can I use pipe in angular template without using import?

Tags: angular, typescript

when using angular built in pipe (such as Date) or if using `custom` pipes, we require import statement in components. E.g.

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

But in templates, we can directly use it without having to "import" anything in 'component'. Why?

I'm guessing angular compiler would finally add the import statement when converting the templates into "javascript", is this so? 
Why cannot we do the same with components?

*Purely out of curiosity*

Comment: I think it's just that Typecript can't compile if it doesn't know that class.

Comment: You still have to import it through CommonModule and add it to the imports array of the module. That's how Angular knows about the pipe

Comment: Look at https://angular.io/api/common

Comment: Also, look at   https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.6/packages/common/PACKAGE.md   where it says  "The CommonModule exports are re-exported by BrowserModule, which is included automatically in the root AppModule when you create a new app with the CLI new command."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes are a declarative feature of Angular just like components.

When you declare a pipe it is added to a module as a declaration.

```
@Pipe({name:'myPipe'})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
   ...
}

@NgModule({
   declarations: [MyPipe]
})
export class PipesModule {}
```

The string value "myPipe" acts much like the selector for a component.

The Angular ahead-of-time compiler will parse all of the modules and read all the declarations. It collects together the selectors and pipe names.

The declarations provide the factory functions needed to create instances of the components and pipes.

When the Angular compile finds an expression `attribute="num | number"` it knows that "number" refers to a pipe because of the `|` character. It will search it's known list of declarations for the factory function.

Angular never uses an *import* statement to gain access to the pipe or components. It has already found them when the compiler parsed the module.

Comment: so why can't similar thing happen for the component? Can we use it in the component without "import"?

Comment: @ZammyPage pipes are only available via the dependency injector. You can not import a pipe and use the new operator to create an instance, because you don't know what dependency it needs. There is no requirement to add a pipe to the providers array of a module. So it's not even standard practice to use them inside a component.

Comment: Not sure what you said is correct. Pipes can be used in component and you can import pipe in component. E.g. `import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';` and use it as `new DatePipe().transform(SomeValue,'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: @ZammyPage you should add the `DatePipe` to the main module as a provider and then inject it into the component. The `async` pipe is an example that takes constructor arguments. I think it needs the view container or something, but the point is to use the DI in Angular. The Angular team did not add the pipes to the common providers, because this would break tree shaking support.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand what you are saying. Why cannot dependency that the pipe needs be injected in the component and use them while creating the pipe instance within component if the constructor of the pipe has some dependencies.

Comment: @ZammyPage because you shouldn't be aware of what the dependencies are. If they add a new dependency in the next release of Angular, then your app will break.

Comment: I think I understand now. Thanks @cgTag. I'll mark this as an answer

Comment: Also, please can you answer why adding the pipes to the common providers, would break tree shaking support?

Comment: @ZammyPage it's my understanding (and maybe things have changed), but Angular can not drop providers during tree shaking, because providers are used outside of a module. Angular doesn't know if they are used. This is why they added the "provideIn" flag for `@Injectable()`. When you provideIn "root" Angular can tree shake the injectable if no code injects it via the constructor.

Comment: Thanks mate. that's gold!